# Is it currently possible for a foreign traveler to buy and use a prepaid SIM card in Argentina?

Tags: internet, argentina

Take, for example Nextel (which I currently find most attractive for my needs, but the question is not limited to this particular operator). According to [this](https://www.nextel.com.ar/planes/prepago.php) one must register the new "line" and [here](https://www.nextel.com.ar/planes/prepago_faq.php#faq-4) it is stated that National Identity Document (DNI) is required. I recall that my friend, with whom I traveled last year, had to go through hoops, maybe even involving using DNI number of a local friend – I do not recall the details – to register the prepaid SIM (I do not know which operator that was).

I plan a 40 day stay in C.A.B.A. and would really like to have reliable mobile internet. This is my second visit, and I know that occasional WiFi hotspots are just not going to be enough for me.

Comment: it's  a great question. P.S. what is CABA ??

Comment: @Fattie, C.A.B.A. stands for Autonomous City of Buenos Aires (Ciudad Autónoma de Buenos Aires). It is frequently used by locals to differentiate from Buenos Aires Province, which is quite often implied by just saying "Buenos Aires".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can answer for Movistar. As with all providers, the sim needs to be registered. In [this post](https://foro.movistar.com.ar/threads/60439-C%C3%B3mo-registro-mi-celular) there is an explanation of the registration process. It says that foreigners cannot do it online (it mentions passports explicitly), but they have to do it in person at some Movistar Centre.

My experience with Movistar has been good. Internet speed in particular has become decent over the last few years.

Comment: I can confirm that this was my actual experience (Jan 2019) as well. I went with Claro. Luckily, one of the employees in the service center knew English. Otherwise I would have to make do with Google Translate.

Comment: You got lucky ;)  You cannot count on people speaking English in Argentina; many can say a few words, but it would be unlikely that you would be able to have any meaningful conversation.